# Set QuickLook window size when previewing with QLPreviewingController.preparePreviewOfFile

Tags: swift, macos, quicklook

I am writing a QuickLook plugin for macOS and everything works, except that I can't set programmatically the window size of the preview.

It starts with 800x600, no matter what I do in the XIB and/or in the code, before and/or after the call to the `completionHandler` of `preparePreviewOfFile`.

Other file types, handled by the default plugin, adapts the preview window size to the content of the file. I would like to do just that.

The preview window is resizable by the user and, once resized, keeps the new size when I select another file in the Finder, to go back to 800x600 if I close it and reopen it on a file handled by my plugin.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QLPreviewingController` should set its `preferredContentSize` so that the window can be sized accordingly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434409-preferredcontentsize

Comment: When I try this, the window appears large at first and then quickly changes to be the preferred size I set. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer, setting `preferredContentSize`, seems to break the autoresizing of all subviews in macOS Catalina. After setting it, the content will no longer track the preview window size when the user resizes it manually or enters fullscreen.

See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137642/setting-preferredcontentsize-of-qlpreviewingcontroller-breaks-auto-resizing).

So I'd like to add the following to the answer: There is no known way to do this on macOS Catalina without breaking autoresizing, but it works fine on macOS Big Sur. The `preferredContentSize` line should be wrapped in a  `#available(macOS 11, *)` guard.